# React native text input blur/focus issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Facing a weird issue on react native when having 2 text inputs. When pressing on central area of onfocused text input, the focus changes correctly, however, when i press on the area that covers ~30-50px from the left of text input, the focused text input gets unfocused and then focuses again.
The issue seems to be same as here: [Input text react native cannot get focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205007/input-text-react-native-cannot-get-focus), however no solution was found on that question.
any ideas on what can cause this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by `gestureEnabled: true` in parent stack navigator.

Comment: How did you fix it? I have the same problem, but i don't want to disable gestures. I didn't find anything about this issue on navigation project github

Comment: In my case focus jumps from one textinput to another when option is enabled and it only happens for android api level < 29

Comment: my bad, navigation by gestures was added in android 10, which is api level 29. However, it shouldn't cause such bugs but adding version checking solved my issue.